# libssh not return command results

Tags: c++, c, linux, ssh, libssh

I am using libssh to send a remote command to a computer. This command is real time so I am trying to get databack as it is generated. Basically I am hexdumping a mouse event and I want that data as it comes in. **How can I make this return realtime results from my command?**

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



/*
 *  1) Set ssh options
 *  2) Connect
 *  3) Authenticate
 *  4) Set channels
 *  5) Execute command
 * */


int main() 
{

    //Initilization
    ssh_session session;
    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    int port   = 22;

    char* password ="root";
    int rc;


    session = ssh_new();
    if (session == NULL)
        return(-1);

    //Set options for SSH connection
    ssh_options_set(session,SSH_OPTIONS_HOST,"90.12.34.44");
    ssh_options_set(session,SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY,&verbosity);
    ssh_options_set(session,SSH_OPTIONS_PORT,&port);

    ssh_options_set(session,SSH_OPTIONS_USER,"root");



    //Connect to server

    rc = ssh_connect(session);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error connecting to host %s\n",ssh_get_error(session));
    ssh_free(session);
    return(-1);
    }



    rc = ssh_userauth_password(session,NULL,password);
    if ( rc == SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Authenticated correctly");

    }


   ssh_channel channel;
   channel = ssh_channel_new(session);
   if(channel == NULL) return SSH_ERROR;

   rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);
   if (rc != SSH_OK)
   {
       ssh_channel_free(channel);
       return rc;
   }


   rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel,"hd /dev/input/event0");
   if (rc != SSH_OK)
   {
       ssh_channel_close(channel);
       ssh_channel_free(channel);
       return rc;
   }



   char buffer[30];
   unsigned int nbytes;

   nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
   while(nbytes > 0)
   {
       if(fwrite(buffer,1,nbytes,stdout));
       {
           ssh_channel_close(channel);
       ssh_channel_free(channel);
       return SSH_ERROR;

       }

       nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);


     if (nbytes < 0)
     {

         ssh_channel_close(channel);
     ssh_channel_free(channel);
     return SSH_ERROR;
     }

    return 0;




}
}
```

Comment: You do know that `fwrite` returns the number of "items" written, so a successful write to `stdout` will be handled as an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get asynchronous real-time responses from remote file being changed, you'd better try some special async I/O API, like **libevent**. You will have to write your own client and server, but it's quite simple. 
Are you sure you need an encrypted connection? If you are, openSSL is supported by **libevent** too.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in this line my friend

```
 nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
```

The last parameters is (0) Zero . If you Change it to (1) one , function will fill the  buffer with the result of your Command .  :D That's it